# How to create a sha256 has (SAS Token) with BearSSL

Tags: arduino-esp8266, azure-iot-sdk

I am trying to generate a SAS token to authenticate to Azure IoT Hub using the PubSub Client in the Tasmota framework https://tasmota.github.io/.

Following an example: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-c/blob/master/sdk/samples/iot/aziot_esp8266/aziot_esp8266.ino, I am able to create a signature for only a 4 character secret when compared to a known good Python example.  When I increase or decrease the length of the secret, the hash does not match.  Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong would be great.

It looks like it is only hashing and encoding the first 4 characters (note how the C code 'mark' = 'markmark').

C Code (run on an ESP8266):

```
#include <bearssl\bearssl.h>  // from https://github.com/arendst/Tasmota/tree/development/lib/lib_ssl
#include <base64.hpp>         // from https://github.com/arendst/Tasmota/tree/development/lib/lib_ssl

const char *PSK = "MBXjqeJm6jNEGa7TvqIEkbRHbRP+U1QhXgxR1+QGoM4=";
const char *dataToSign = "mark";

br_sha256_context sha256_context;
br_hmac_key_context hmac_key_context;
br_hmac_context hmac_context;

unsigned char decodedPSK[32];
unsigned char encryptedSignature[100];
unsigned char encodedSignature[100];

// need to base64 decode the Preshared key and the length
int base64_decoded_device_length = decode_base64((unsigned char*)PSK, decodedPSK);

// create the sha256 hmac and hash the data
br_sha256_init(&sha256_context);
br_hmac_key_init(&hmac_key_context, sha256_context.vtable, decodedPSK, base64_decoded_device_length);
br_hmac_init(&hmac_context, &hmac_key_context, 32);
br_hmac_update(&hmac_context, dataToSign, sizeof(dataToSign));
br_hmac_out(&hmac_context, encryptedSignature);

// base64 decode the HMAC to a char
encode_base64(encryptedSignature, br_hmac_size(&hmac_context), encodedSignature);

printf("PSK is %s \n", PSK);
printf("decodedPSK is %s \n", decodedPSK);
printf("dataToSign is %s \n", dataToSign);
printf("encryptedSignature is %s \n", encryptedSignature);
printf("encodedSignature is %s \n", encodedSignature);
```

Python code:

```
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from hashlib import sha256
from urllib.parse import quote_plus, urlencode
from hmac import HMAC
PSK="MBXjqeJm6jNEGa7TvqIEkbRHbRP+U1QhXgxR1+QGoM4="
sign_key = "mark".encode('utf-8')
signature = b64encode(HMAC(b64decode(PSK), sign_key, sha256).digest())
print('PSK = ' + PSK)
print('sign_key = ' + str(sign_key))
print('signature = ' + str(signature))
```

If set `dataToSign` to mark, the hash matches:

C output:

```
PSK is MBXjqeJm6jNEGa7TvqIEkbRHbRP+U1QhXgxR1+QGoM4=
ecodedPSK is 0␕��f�3D␙�Ӿ�␄��Gm␓�ST!^␌Q��␆��
dataToSign is mark
encryptedSignature is ␝�8)����jLQ��␃b!��x␞Ǿ2��1�W␗S4���?���?�␕�? 
encodedSignature is Hak4Kaic0vtqTFGSlQNiIeeD6ngex74yoOExgVcXUzQ=
```

Python output:

```
C:/Python38-64/python.exe d:/Git/createsastoken/generate/test.py
PSK = MBXjqeJm6jNEGa7TvqIEkbRHbRP+U1QhXgxR1+QGoM4=
sign_key = b'mark'
signature = b'Hak4Kaic0vtqTFGSlQNiIeeD6ngex74yoOExgVcXUzQ=
```

If I change the `dataToSign` to 'markmark', they do not match:

C Output:

```
PSK is MBXjqeJm6jNEGa7TvqIEkbRHbRP+U1QhXgxR1+QGoM4=
ecodedPSK is 0␕��f�3D␙�Ӿ�␄��Gm␓�ST!^␌Q��␆��
dataToSign is markmark
encryptedSignature is ␝�8)����jLQ��␃b!��x␞Ǿ2��1�W␗S4���?���?�␕�? 
encodedSignature is Hak4Kaic0vtqTFGSlQNiIeeD6ngex74yoOExgVcXUzQ=
```

Python Output:

```
C:/Python38-64/python.exe d:/Git/createsastoken/generate/test.py
PSK = MBXjqeJm6jNEGa7TvqIEkbRHbRP+U1QhXgxR1+QGoM4=
sign_key = b'markmark'
signature = b'XSf//iSjx9hB6lOQe5lcYkxLGWY+g5oXM8AX0XVGIh4='
```

This problem also happens if I make the `dataToSign` shorter, example 'joe'.

C Output:

```
PSK is MBXjqeJm6jNEGa7TvqIEkbRHbRP+U1QhXgxR1+QGoM4=
ecodedPSK is 0␕��f�3D␙�Ӿ�␄��Gm␓�ST!^␌Q��␆��
dataToSign is joe
encryptedSignature is ~����␕�␡
encodedSignature is fp21m4IVnH8Arfnpb1SNY3HifxunD5se9QwF/KA3z2E=
```

Python:

```
& C:/Python38-64/python.exe d:/Git/createsastoken/generate/test.py
PSK = MBXjqeJm6jNEGa7TvqIEkbRHbRP+U1QhXgxR1+QGoM4=
sign_key = b'joe'
signature = b'69FWap6f/xD4JauDwia5y9fqYdq8qnSH5F7Yo5aa4FI='
```

Comment: Thanks Mark.  Spot on as always.  :)

Answer (score 2):

The sizeof

```
const char *dataToSign = "mark";
```

will always be four because it is a pointer (at least on a 32 bit system). Thus it works for 'mark' but fails for 'joe' and 'markmark'.
Declare it as

```
const char dataToSign[] = "whatever...";
```

Then sizeof will give you the array size but this will include the terminating zero so you will need to subtract one.